# multiple conditions for select value

Tags: jquery

I need to display a text box if a select's value is 'A' or 'B' and the text box isn't already visible, I don't want to keep inserting text boxes - I just need the one. If the selected option is something else, I need to remove the text box. With the code below, when I select "B" it is duplicating the text box, but selecting "A" will remove it...

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>

$('#mySelect').on('change', funciton() {
   if($(this).val() == 'A' || $(this).val() == 'B' && ('#myTextInput").length < 0 {
       $('input[type="text" id="myTextInput"]).insertAfter('#mySelect');
   } else {
       $('#myTextInput').remove();
    }
)};
```

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7PpVR/)

Answer (score 1):

The keyword is parentheses/brackets!

From:

```
($(this).val() == 'A' || $(this).val() == 'B' && ('#myTextInput').length < 0
```

To:

```
(($(this).val() == 'A' || $(this).val() == 'B') && ('#myTextInput').length < 0)
```

Comment: Cant seem to get that to work either, I added a fiddle - could you take a look pls? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if( 
    ( $(this).val() == 'A' || $(this).val() == 'B') 
    && 
    $('#myTextInput').length < 0
   ) 
 {
 //....//
```

Be aware about your parentheses and the order of logic operations.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of errors in your code, fixed below:

```
$('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
   if(($(this).val() == 'A' || $(this).val() == 'B') && $('#myTextInput').length < 0 {
       $('#myTextInput').insertAfter('#mySelect');
   } else {
       $('#myTextInput').remove();
    }
)};
```

Comment: there's a couple in yours as well 'unexpected token'

Answer (score 0):

There was quite a number of different syntax and logical errors in your code. Below is a snippet of a fixed version.

- Your input's id is `myText` but you were looking for `#myTextInput`
- You put the closing `)` of your `.on()` function in the wrong place
- You forgot `$` before `('#myText')`
- You misspelled `function` as *funciton*
- You were looking for `$('#myText').length < 0` which will always be false, since `length` will be `0` when it doesn't exist.

I think that was all.

What are you using to write your code? I suggest you use an IDE that supports javascript. It would make most of these errors very easy to spot.

```js
$('#mySelect').on("change", function() {
  var myTextInput = '<input type="text" id="myText">';
  if (($(this).val() == 'A' || $(this).val() == 'B') && ($('#myText').length <= 0)) {
    $(myTextInput).insertAfter('#mySelect');
  } else {
    $('#myText').remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```